# How to display the username credentials used in a SOAP WCF call?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

The SOAP call below works fine using my credentials but when other people use my .EXE which calls the WCF service I get a 401 denied. I am trying to find out what are the credentials being passed.

I could look at the IIS logs but am trying to do it programatically, thanks:

```
   public static Guid GetServerID(string serverName, string soapUrl)
    {
        Guid result;
        try
        {
            Guid vServerId = new ControllerWS.Controller
            {
                Url = soapUrl,
                Timeout = Config.SoapCallTimeOut,
                Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            }.GetServerId(serverName);
            result = vServerId;

            //Console.WriteLine("CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials: " + CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.ToString());
            //ICredentials Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.GetCredential()
        }
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It realy depends what type of authentication you are using. When windows credentials with impersonation then you can get username like this:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

If you are using plain username and password than those values can be stored inside request header and read like this:

```
MessageHeaders headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
string userId = headers.GetHeader<Guid>("MyKey", "MyNamespce");
```

Comment: thank you, it is calling as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM :( I wish it would take the IIS Application Pool indentity. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) on the server side to intercept the full message including headers.  From there you can inspect the credentials that are being passed in.

[Here's a blog post](http://cgeers.com/2011/05/10/wcf-message-logging/) outlining how to log the full message from the message inspector including the configuration steps you need to do to wire it up.

Comment: thank you, it is calling as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM :( I wish it would take the IIS Application Pool indentity. Thanks !

Comment: I take that back. Another process running under SYSTEM is calling my .EXE which calls the web service with the SOAP call.